# rake db:migrate error with mysql2 gem - Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, mysql2

Getting the following error after running rake db:migrate

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/scott/Google Drive/playground/myApp/myApp/config/application.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/scott/Google Drive/playground/myApp/myApp/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

What does the libssl refer to?

Comment: Can you show us code sample, what have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I have tried most solutions on stackoverflow - 1) adding mysql to PATH 2) installing newer gem version of mysql2 (0.4.10) since my installation instructions asked for 0.4.5 3) and lastly, this solution - https://afshinm.name/2016/02/05/how-to-fix-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: @Gabbar what code sample would you like, and how would that help?  I'm installing a Rails App from github which I'd like to contribute to.

Comment: Are you on Mac? Maybe use `brew`, or your preferred package manager to install libssl.

Comment: Yeah on a Mac.  Tried that also, didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer to my own question was the following - out of the 5 or so other solutions on stackoverflow, this is the only one that worked:

```
brew install openssl

cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1f/lib

sudo cp libssl.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/
```

Full solution here - https://mithun.co/hacks/library-not-loaded-libcrypto-1-0-0-dylib-issue-in-mac/

Comment: NO! :(. I followed these commands and it installed here the MySQL 8.0 locally, but my project need to be with MySQL 5.7 version. Therefore, these commands completely messes up my project and **it was required to reinstall the mysql completely**.

Answer (score 29):

First uninstall the mysql2 gem:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
```

Make sure you installed openssl:

```
brew install openssl
```

It will print out some notes. We are interested in this part:

```
For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Then you can re-install mysql2 gem like this:

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.10 -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

You should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, @michael. I was trying to fix a bug for weeks now and the solution you provided is the one that worked. What a relief, man!

Comment: This is the correct answer, though I had to run `brew reinstall openssl` to see these notes since I already had it installed.

Comment: This is almost right answer for me. After installing check the output:
```For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```
use those flags listed in output when installing mysql2 gem

Answer (score 8):

Following fix solves the issue

```
   ==> cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/

==> sudo cp libssl.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case just uninstalling and installing the mysql2 gem did the trick

```
$ gem uninstall mysql2
```

```
$ bundle install 
> Fetching mysql2 0.4.10
> Installing mysql2 0.4.10 with native extensions
```

Answer (score 1):

just one command:

`gem pristine mysql2`

then i fix this problem

Comment: Well, it worked here! This should be marked as the right answer. Simple, but effective, like ALL things SHOULD be. Thanks.

Comment: Well... I remove my words, this installed MySQL version 8.0 here and bugged everything. On my case I still need to keep with the MySQL version 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

For users of `rbenv`:

```
 brew uninstall openssl
 brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0

 gem uninstall mysql2
 gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.10' -- --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the later versions of mysql2 (0.5.3 in my case) needed openssl1.1.  After doing this, it worked for me:

```
$  cp /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1j/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib
$  cp /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1j/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib
```