# 'Error: Rake aborted' when trying to use db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rake

I am new to Ruby on rails, so I was following the instructions to install ROR from gorails.com, with mysql as database. (Have also tried using SQLite3, but I am getting an error there as well...?) https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave

Everything went well until I had to use following,

```
rake db:create
```

When I run this command inside my ROR project, I get this rake aborted error. With following output from my terminal.

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/username/Desktop/myapp3/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/username/Desktop/myapp3/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/Users/username/Desktop/myapp3/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have tried to check the gemfile.

Comment: prob mac.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264240/rake-dbmigrate-error-with-mysql2-gem-library-not-loaded-libssl-1-0-0-dylib

Comment: This helped me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used the answers from @Denny Mueller and @Umar Khan to fix the problem. I did not realise it was a problem with the openssl, but the solution to the problem is the same as the answer [provided by Michael Erb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264240/rake-dbmigrate-error-with-mysql2-gem-library-not-loaded-libssl-1-0-0-dylib) on this question.

**The Solution**

As it turns out, openssl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own libs.
Firstly, uninstall mysql2.

```
gem uninstall mysql2
```

Then reinstall OpenSSL

```
brew reinstall openssl
```

Notice the output containing:

```
LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Then we can install mysql2 again

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.10 -- --with-cppflags=-`I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
brew install openssl

cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1f/lib

sudo cp libssl.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/
```

You can find a full solution here - https://mithun.co/hacks/library-not-loaded-libcrypto-1-0-0-dylib-issue-in-mac/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22343407)

Comment: @Jondiedoop I believe now it deserve upvote not downvote :)

Comment: I wasnt the downvoter. So i can not retract it. I do not consider myself experienced enough in ruby to judge whether it deserves an upvote, but the community does. Dont worry.