# Could not load OpenSSL while installing bundle in Mac OS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

getting bellow error while executing `bundle install` in Mac OS

```
Could not load OpenSSL.
You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your
Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using
RVM are available at http://rvm.io/packages/openssl.
```

I checked for the version of openssl

```
openssl version -a
```

i got below results

```
LibreSSL 2.6.5
built on: date not available
platform: information not available
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: information not available
OPENSSLDIR: "/private/etc/ssl"
```

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156390/managing-system-dependencies-of-ruby-gems-e-g-mysql2-and-openssl/59158744#59158744

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Managing system dependencies of ruby gems (e.g. mysql2 and openssl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156390/managing-system-dependencies-of-ruby-gems-e-g-mysql2-and-openssl)